# Strange beeps while booting and currupt BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I have an ASROCK motherboard..

every time i unplug/switch off the power supply to the machine.. its BIOS currupts..
everytime I boot, i have to press the F1 key to continue booting..

and then the most annoying part..
first of all the booting slows.. and secondly the PC starts beeping in 3-4 seconds..

there is a beep then disk spinning noise.. then beep then disk spinning.. it continues firstly at the manufacturer screen then the windows logo where it stucks.. the dots spin endlessly..

until i viberate the case by hitting it gently..

sometimes the beep stops.. sometimes the next part of booting continues.. the black screen with spinning dots then lock screen.. strangely.. no inputs work.. until i hit it again and finally the beep stops..

then i enter the password.. go in ans see a prompt saying

"New Volume (D:,E:,F:) Found!
select what to do with this removable drives"

the beep stops and the PC is functional again..

i suppose the HDD is problematic.. but chkdsk doesn't show anything.. also i think the SATA cable is loose that will explain the hitting method..

please help me on these 2 problems..

Comment: Change the SATA cable.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS corruption can occur when your mainboard BIOS buffer battery is exhausted and its voltage becomes too low.

Replace the mainboard BIOS buffer battery. Typically this is a CR2032 type.
Upon restart run "load setup defaults" in your BIOS. This is to ensure that your memory that is battery buffered will be initialized with compatible values.
You can change the settings for your your individual setup after successfully rebooting.

If you have a multimeter, measure the voltage of the old and the new battery.
New ones tend to have around 3,3 V. If your mainboard is doing fine with the new battery you will get a rough idea at which voltage your mainboard fails.

Write down both voltages for the next change.